# Will implementing HSTS cause parts of my website which use IE6 compatibility mode to break?

Tags: hsts, internet-explorer, cloudflare

I am converting a legacy system designed for IE6 to work on modern browsers.

Those parts of the site which have not yet been converted, will only work on Internet Explorer, and the IE6 emulation is provided via the following tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

I am planning on adding HSTS to the site ([via CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204183088-Understanding-HSTS-HTTP-Strict-Transport-Security-)).
I see that HSTS is supported only for [Internet Explorer 11 and higher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Browser_support).

Will adding HSTS cause those parts of my site which rely on IE6 emulation to break?

Comment: As other community members had informed you, in a general situation, it should work fine. As we don't know anything about your site and how it is configured with the CloudFare, I suggest you try to make a test on a dummy small scale site with the HSTS. Test it on the IE 6 mode and with the IE 11. It can help you to verify whether any issue can arise or not. If your test site works without issue then it will be easy for you to continue with this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X-UA-Compatibilty` is mainly about HTML rendering of content designed for older versions of IE in newer IE versions. It has by itself nothing to do with HSTS. Adding HSTS probably will be interpreted by the browser even when the HTML content asks for compatibility mode - because HSTS is about the connection (transport of HTML data) and compatibility mode is about the content (interpretation of HTML data). But as long as the site worked before without problems with HTTPS then the added HSTS will not cause additional problems.

Answer (score 5):

No.  IE6 will not know what to do with the HSTS header, and simply ignore it.

Comment: That's probably the shortest answer I've ever given +1 to, but there's really not much else to say. :D

Comment: The OP is not running IE6 and is also not asking about the effect of this header on IE6. __This is about IE6 emulation mode__, i.e. compatibility hacks inside newer IE versions which are used to support sites designed for IE6. This `X-UA-Compatibilty` is mainly about HTML rendering.